# Tensor equation of a line

Tags: tensors

So, tensors appear to have no good description on the internet that actually starts from the basics.

I've put together so far that, philosophically, tensors form a way to do your math in frames but independent of coordinate systems with the understanding that, when you go to implement the system, you'll select a convenient coordinate system. This system also appears to make more complex equations easier, but I'll save that for later.

So, to start from the beginning, the equation of a line:

```
P = P0 + dP*t
```

But what does this look like with tensors? For example, this line may be an orbital body, so the form the result would look different in polar vs Cartesian coordinates, but the tensor equation must look the same. So what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

It would be simply as making depend the components of a tensor $T=\tau^k$ as 
$$\tau^k=\tau^k(t),$$
that is, taking in them as depending on only one parameter. Observe that $k$ could be a multi-index.

Comment: This seems like cheating because I could just to find my final result as being a function of time as well. If I were to define what the tensor T is in tensors, what would that look like?

Comment: Define, not "to find" - stupid dictation

Comment: consider that tensors are not only defined over vector spaces but also over more general topologies such as manifolds, so the notion of straight line maybe is not defined on, but alternatives are still available:  paths, trajectories or curves (that are 1-dimensional subsets)